# Writing to text file in app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

After continuous search on google, I still can't seem to figure out this problem with app inventor 2.
My question is how can I write to text file as initial value without user input. For example I want to store '6' as the initial value in a text file, there are ways to do it by clicking on button but is there a way to store the initial value without getting the user to enter a value? Also would this value be available each time the app is run? or would I need to set the initial value each time?

Many Thanks in advace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to store the initial value without getting the user to
>   enter a value?

Normally you would use a variable to store an initial value. You do not have to store that in a file! But if you like to use a file, you can use the `Screen.Initialize` event

[image]

see also the [documentation of the File component](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/components/storage.html#File)

> Also would this value be available each time the app is run?

yes, but only if the user did not delete the file manually...

> or would I need to set the initial value each time?

Please first **do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html)** **to lean the basics of App Inventor!**